Substitution effect on giffen goods
the substitution effect shows us the effect on demand due to changes in relative prices. and that is always positive, but why? for giffen goods the definition is that if prices decrease, the demand decreases. so it's negative. why is it positive under the substitution effect? i understand that there is the later addition of the income effect etc. but under this shouldn't it be negative? (english is not my first language so excuse the unprettyness)
